# Is it better to have a service that run at full time but most of time waiting timer or a service that start/stop via indent

Tags: android, android-service

Is it better to have a service that run at full time but in loop sleep 5 min, check the geolocation, sleep 5 min, check the geolocation, ... and so. Or to have a service that will be start/stop every time a location update will be detected ?

The question, does it's will use more consumption and CPU to start/stop all the time the service or it's will be more efficient to let the service running at full time (even if in 95% of the time the service is just sleeping and waiting)

Comment: Use an intent service like google suggests

Comment: where you see that google suggest it ? any source ?